Sim vs Reality difference publishing
I have a node that creates a grid map with obstacles from a pointcloud input. After testing, I've realized that the grid map is being published at 2 Hz in real tests while in simulation (gazebo) its frequency is 10 Hz.
I've already compared both cases using pointclouds with the same number of points but the difference is still there.
For clarity, robot's computer is more powerful than the one used in simulation.
Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need part of the code to help me.
EDIT: I'm using ROS melodic. The rate of the input topic (pointcloud) is 10 Hz for both. Sim time is set during simulations.

Welcome to Robotics, Alejandro. Do you have sim time set during simulations?

Additional questions: Are you using ros1 or ros2? On the real robot, is the time-of-day clock set accurately? While logged into the real robot, have you checked the rate at which the lidar publishes to the scan topic?

Is the input pointcloud frequency the same as well on both?
I would suggest you to record a bag of the pointcloud from gazebo and run it on the real robot as well!
